# Как отловить нажатие по кнопке: буквы, цифры, знаки препинания на любой раскладке

Tags: javascript

Как обработать событие нажатия по кнопке, только если нажата буква или цифра или знак препинания при нажатии на русской или английской раскладке?

Comment: [a-zA-Zа-яА-Я\d.,]

Comment: Тут символами не отделаешься... надо коды мониторить `event.keyCode`. А они от раскладки могут очень неоднозначно зависеть

Comment: Sultanov Shamil, спасибо!

Comment: DNS, да, спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отлавливаем нажатие переводим код в символ и применяем regexp как обычно:

```
$(document).on("keypress", function (e) {
    var _event = e || window.event;
    var key = _event.keyCode || _event.which;
    console.log(key);
    key = String.fromCharCode(key);
    console.log(key);
    if(/[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я\d.,]/.test(key)) {
        console.log('success');
        //тут триггер на нажатие кнопки итд   
    }    

});
```